# Проблема с подключениями файлов классов

Tags: c++, классы, include

Задача вкратце.

Есть файлы `vector.h` и `vector.cpp`, соответственно, содержащие описание и реализацию класса `vector`.

Есть файлы `point.h` и `point.cpp`, таким же образом содержащие описание и реализацию класса `point`.

Оба класса должны знать друг о друге. Т.е. в классе `point` есть функция имеющая параметр типа `vector`. И наоборот.

Есть условный `main.cpp`, который должен работать с обоими классами.

Как правильно реализовать подключение файлов в проекте?

Все `.h` файлы имеют конструкцию такого вида:

```
#ifnden HEADERFILENAME_H
#define HEADERFILENAME_H

// Class definition.

#endif // HEADERFILENAME_H
```

Comment: @Gordory  Не понятно, какая у вас возникает проблема? Можно конкретнее?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow проблемы две.
Одну решил @Harry,
Вторая заключается в следующей ошибке:
undefined reference to `vector<int, 3u>::vector()` при создании объекта класса vector.

При этом в main я делаю #include "vector.h" #include "point.h"

Comment: @VladfromMoscow дополнительно, если в main подключить vector.cpp и point.cpp то все работает.

Comment: @Gordory А в проект ваши vector.cpp и point.cpp включены? Они линкуются вместе с main? Судя по тому, что вы пишете - они просто не включены в проект.

Comment: @Harry , разумеется. Среда QtCreator, вот частичное содержимое .pro файла:

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    point.cpp \
    vector.cpp

HEADERS += \
    point.h \
    vector.h

Comment: @Gordory C этой средой не ко мне (не работал), надеюсь, тут более сведущие люди подскажут, как правильно подключаются файлы. Просто вижу, что это диагностика линковщика, об отсутствии того, что у вас, судя по вашему описанию, находится в vector.cpp.

Comment: @Harry в таком случае cycle-include и это - две разные проблемы. Спасибо за решение первой.
Буду гуглить конкретно по среде.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надеюсь, параметры представляют собой ссылки (или указатели) на `vector` и `point`? Иначе толку не будет.

А тек - просто объявите о существовании классов (forward declaration):

В `vector.h` до класса `vector` напишите

```
class point;
```

То же самое - в `point.h`:

```
class vector;
```